# Десериализация Json, нужно отобрать объекты uid

Tags: c#, json

Есть такого вида json. Я пробовал вытащить классами разными методами, но не вызывается uid никак, т.к. мешают меняющиеся цифры в объекте. Вот мои варианты, поправьте где я не так написал

```
 public class Root
    {
        public bool ok;
        public gList jsonList;
    }
public class gList
    {
        public string uid;
    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string json = @"{
"ok": true,
"gList": {
    "8995268": {
        "uid": "8995268",
    },
    "9054265": {
        "uid": "9054265",
    },
    "9065748": {
        "uid": "9065748",
    },
    "9086253": {
        "uid": "9086253",
    },
    "9097542": {
        "uid": "9097542",
    },
}
}";
        textBox1.AppendText(json);

        gList param = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<gList>(json);
        textBox2.Text = param.uid;
    }
```

или такой второй вариант, но он выдал ошибку

```
public class Root
    {
        public bool ok;
        public gList jsonList;
    }

public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Param2>> gList;

        public string gKey(int index)
        {
            string key = "";
            int i = 1;
            foreach (var pair in gList)
            {
                if (i == index)
                {
                    key = pair.Key;
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
            return key;
        }
public class Param2
    {
        public string uid;
    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string json = @"{
"ok": true,
"gList": {
    "8995268": {
        "uid": "8995268",
    },
    "9054265": {
        "uid": "9054265",
    },
    "9065748": {
        "uid": "9065748",
    },
    "9086253": {
        "uid": "9086253",
    },
    "9097542": {
        "uid": "9097542",
    },
}
}";
        textBox1.AppendText(json);

        gList param = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<gList>(json);
        textBox2.Text = param.gkey(1);
    }
```

Ошибка в результате выполнения программы:
Необработанное исключение типа "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException" в Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Дополнительные сведения: Error converting value "8995268" to type 'WindowsForm.Form1+Param2'. Path 'gList.6577549.uid', line 1, position 91.

Comment: а язык какой? отформатируйте код, что бы его было легче читать.

Comment: C#, код и так отформатирован

Comment: добавьте информацию об ошибке

Comment: Эм.. А кавычки кто удваивать будет?

Comment: Добавил ошибку при выполнении программы. Не понял про кавычки...

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью Json.Linq.

```
var json = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("test.json"));

var uids = json.Descendants()
    .OfType<JProperty>()
    .Where(p => p.Name == "uid");

foreach (var uid in uids)
    Console.WriteLine(uid.Value);
```